# OBTENER CADENA CON ESTE FORMATO 3 digitos + " " + 4 digitos,

Tags: java-8

quisiera formatear una cadena con el siguiente formato "xxx xxxx" es decir 3 dígitos + " " + 4 dígitos utilizando API STREAM.

También hacer que si la cadena tiene menos de 7 dígitos, se complete con 0 a la derecha y que cumpla con el formato requerido es decir 3 dígitos + " " + 4 dígitos,

EJEMPLOS:

- "xxx x" a "xxx x000"
- "x" a "x00 0000"
- "" a "000 0000"

Y cuando la cadena tenga mas de 7 dígitos, se cortara a 7 dígitos y  y que cumpla con el formato requerido es decir 3 dígitos + " " + 4 dígitos,

EJEMPLO

- "xxxxxxxl" a "xxx xxxx"

Por el momento este es mi avance

```
String finalValue = StringUtils.substring(StringUtils.rightPad(value, 7, "0"), 0, 7);
String variable = Stream.of(StringUtils.substring(finalValue, 0, 3), StringUtils.substring(finalValue, 3, 7)) .collect(Collectors.joining(StringUtils.SPACE));
```

gracias por el apoyo

Comment: y que has intentado, te recomiendo que pases por el [tour]

Comment: String finalValue = StringUtils.substring(StringUtils.rightPad(value, 7, "0"), 0, 7);
      String variable = Stream.of(StringUtils.substring(finalValue, 0, 3), StringUtils.substring(finalValue, 3, 7))
          .collect(Collectors.joining(StringUtils.SPACE));

Comment: por el momento es lo que he avanzado

Comment: entendido. gracias

Comment: un compañero de al comunidad ha respondido tu pregunta, evalua si esta es correcta y puedes marcarla como resuelta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una sencilla función `padRight` de esta manera

<sub>Una función `padRight` agrega 'n' caracteres a la derecha y padLeft agrega funciones a la izquierda</sub>

```
public static String padRight(String s, char fill, int padSize) {
    int repeats = Math.max(0, padSize - s.length());
    return s + Character.toString(fill).repeat(repeats);
}
```

Luego otra función que de el formato requerido `3digitos 4digitos`, donde llamamos la función anterior que nos entregará siempre un `String` de al menos largo 7, este string lo dividimos en 2 partes (una de 3 y la otra de 4)

```
public static String format(String str) {
   String str7 = padRight(str,'0',7);
   return str7.substring(0, 3) + " " + str7.substring(3, 7);
}
```

Y luego para usarlo

```
System.out.println(format("x")); //x00 0000
System.out.println(format("xx"));  //xx0 0000
System.out.println(format("xxx")); //xxx 0000
System.out.println(format("xxxxx")); // xxx xx00
System.out.println(format("xxxxxx")); //xxx xxx0
System.out.println(format("xxxxxxx")); //xxx xxxx
System.out.println(format("xxxxxxxx")); //xxx xxxx
System.out.println(format("xxxxxxxxx")); //xxx xxxx
```